# Match letters before matching a space character in regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this regex -: `/@[a-zA-Z ]+/g;`
Clearly, this would match `@abs` as well as it would match
 `@ abs`. But I dont want the latter to match cuz it has a `space character` before a `letter`. My regex should only match those where space is preceeded by a letter.

How to do that?

Comment: @MichaelSazonov that would force a space after the @, which is not what the poster wanted. he wanted no space after the @.

Answer (score 4):

putting `[a-zA-Z]` after the @ would force a letter there: 
`/@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*/g;`

Comment: If you want the regex to match when there is only one letter (such as `@a`), replace the `+` with `*`.

Answer (score -1):

You accidently added a space in your regex after Z

/@[a-zA-Z ]/

Comment: that space was meant there. As I understand it, the poster wants this to be valid: `@hello world`, but this to be invalid: `@ hello`